# IText7 SignatureUtilities GetTranslatedFieldName return string does not match field (result missing "Page1[0].")

Tags: itext, itext7

I have been trying to rewrite some logic to use IText7 that I had previously working with ITextSharp (5.x) but ran into a roadblock. `GetTranslatedFieldName` no longer existed so I did a quick search and found it in `SignatureUtilities` but the result doesn't match the actual field name. I assumed that maybe I was misusing it so I dug around a bit more and found `FindFieldName` on the `AcroForm` but it returns the same incorrect field name.

Is this a bug or am I still misusing these methods? Is there a native way to Retrieve the full field name from a partial name in IText7?

For reference this is what my full field name looks like

> someFormX[0].Page1[0].FieldX[0]

And this is what the field name being returned by `GetTranslatedFieldName` and `FindFieldName` looks like

> someFormX[0].FieldX[0]

Comment: Please share an example pdf illustrating that issue.

Comment: I actually can't, they are government forms that I don't think I am allowed to share and that I cannot edit. Is there any information I can query with iText/Sharp to provide?

Comment: You can try to find a non-restricted pdf form you can reproduce the issue with. If you cannot find such a form, chances are that there is an issue with the very form in question, not a general or itext issue.

Comment: I see, I guess that means I am doing the right thing? Any idea why it worked on this form in ITextSharp 5?

Comment: Sorry, no specific idea. Probably itext 5 was somewhere more lax in its code than itext 7, so an issue in the pdf did not result in an unwanted output. Or probably there is a buff in itext 7. But then a sample pdf to reproduce the issue with is needed.

Comment: Do you know if it is possible to create an editable copy of the base structure of a PDF without the password? If I could strip out all of the proprietary stuff I could share to make sure it isn't an itext7 issue

Comment: What do you mean by *"the base structure of a PDF without the password"*? Merely your pdf without password? Or should something else also be removed?

Comment: Sorry, I am not super familiar with how PDFs work. What I meant was a minimal version of my PDF that reproduces the problem. I just don't think I am allowed to share the actual PDF so I was hoping to either strip all content and identifying data out of the PDF or recreate the issue in a barebones PDF. I was hoping there was some way to filter out everything except for the fields themselves.

Comment: Well, you could remove all the content streams of your document. But that might merely hide the actual sensitive contents, not remove them. As I don't know your specific documents, I don't know what is required to remove sensitive contents.

Comment: Alright. Thank you for the input, I will poke it a bit and see if I can figure anything out.